# Unable to Find npm install -g @angular/cli@latest in devDependencies

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, npm

`ng build` gives an error that

> Unable to Find npm install -g @angular/cli@latest in devDependencies.

To start application using `npm start`, but when I try to build a file it is Giving me an error Message in CMD:

> Unable to find "@angular/cli" in devDependencies. Please take the
>   following steps to avoid issues: "npm install --save-dev
>   @angular/cli@latest" Versions of @angular/compiler-cli and typescript
>   could not be determined. The most common reason for this is a broken
>   npm install. Please make sure your package.json contains both
>   @angular/compiler-cli and typescript in devDependencies, then delete
>   node_modules and package-lock.json (if you have one) and run npm
>   install again.

I follow all the step as it suggest me in Error message, but still it is giving me same message [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ou7lw.png)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue following steps helped me to resolve it,

```
Update package json
from
"angular-cli": "anything"
to
"@angular/cli": "1.0.4"

Deleted node_modules and installed node modules again with
npm install

Change angular-cli.json for
from
"environments": {
"source": "environments/environment.ts"
"dev": "environments/environment.ts",
"prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
}
to
"environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
"environments": {
"dev": "environments/environment.ts",
"prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have a problem with your `node_modules`. Delete the node_modules and `package-lock.json` and be sure you have all the dependencies in your `package.json`. After that run npm install

Another point could be that you don't have installed the `@angular/cli` module.

Like in the error message said, try to install this package with `npm install -g @angular/cli`.

Comment: I follow the steps you mention, but now one more error I am facing **The "@angular/compiler-cli" package was not properly installed. **  [link] (https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5654), I tried a solutions given but it is also not working.

Comment: Can you post your package.json?